# EKEventStore.calendars is always empty after clean install

Tags: swift, ekeventstore

I have a weird issue on my iOS app where, after a fresh install, if I try to add calendar events (after accepting the native calendar permissions prompt), my eventStore singleton never shows any available calendars, and `defaultCalendarForNewEvents` is always `nil`.

I've tried to debug it, and the odd part is that, if I try `po EKEventStore().calendars(for: .event)`, then I can see them all (still on fresh install).

If I then kill the app and reopen it, my eventStore singleton suddenly starts working as expected.

I'm not sure if this behaviour has been documented before, it seems very strange to me and I couldn't find other posts with this specific issue...

Hereafter a snippet of my `CalendarManager` class and how the eventStore singleton is declared.

```
class CalendarManager {
    // MARK: Variables
    static let sharedInstance = CalendarManager()
    fileprivate init() { }

    let eventStore = EKEventStore()

    // further business logic...
}
```

And further down, the code where I encounter issues:

```
func createEvent(for workout: Workout, sendReminder: Bool = false) -> Bool {
    // If I add a breakpoint below and check a new instance of EKEventStore, 
    // I can see all calendars & defaultCalendarForNewEvents, 
    // however this `guard` never lets us through...
    guard let calendar = CalendarManager.sharedInstance.eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents else { return false }

    // create event with default calendar...
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this issue, I've ran into it myself now - where `eventStore.sources` is empty on first load of the app, right after granting permissions - seems to be similar root cause?

Comment: @10623169 Yes I did actually, AjaBeckett's answer below was the solution. Basically just make your singleton's eventStore a var, and re-instantiate it right after permissions are granted.

Comment: ahh I see, I actually fixed my issue after posting this comment - turns out I was querying the `eventStore` once before permissions were granted. So even after granting permissions to my instance on the Singleton, i.e. inside the `requestAccess` completion closure, it was still returning no sources/calendars (because I had "illegally" queried the instance before getting permissions), seems even doing this once, for an instance, basically makes it unreadable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you aren't initializing EKEventStore before requesting calendar permissions.

Comment: That fixed it; I basically just re-instantiate my eventStore var right after permissions are granted, and everything works as expected

Comment: I have question. Do I need to request permissions every time before I initialize EKEventStore? I mean.. if at the begging of app launch, I ask users for permission. Then in the future, if I want to initialize the store, do I need to "re-ask" again? Since the permission is already granted. Thank you