# EKEventStore does not return any data

Tags: swift, macos, eventkit

Hello I am writing a super simple mac app to retrieve events from my calendars. It should be very straight forward but somehow I do not get any data from `EKEventStore` neither events nor calendars etc.

I have the following code:

```
func getEvents(completion: @escaping ([EKEvent]) -> ()) {
    self.store.requestAccess(to: .event) { granted, error in
        guard granted, error == nil else {
            print("no access")
            return
        }
        
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        var startComponents = DateComponents()
        startComponents.month = -2
        let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: startComponents, to: Date())
        
        var endComponents = DateComponents()
        endComponents.day = -1
        let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: endComponents, to: Date())
        
        guard let startDate = startDate, let endDate = endDate else {
            print("dates are broken")
            completion([])
            return
        }
        
        let predicate = self.store.predicateForEvents(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, calendars: nil)
        print("startDate: \(startDate), endDate: \(endDate), predicate: \(predicate)")
        completion(self.store.events(matching: predicate))
    }
}
```

and have `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` set in the `info.plist`
However I always get an empty array. I tried just retrieving all calendars - `self.store.calendars(for: .event)` to see if there is an error in my predicate for the events and still an empty array.

I believe am doing everything the documentation says. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Per [EKEventStore.calendars is always empty after clean install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58873603), try re-instantiating the eventStore right after permission is granted.

Comment: Idk why but somehow the code works fine now. And I instantiate my event store at its declaration actually. Weird

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32820842)